# Scala - Iterator being 'consumed'

Tags: scala, iterator

I am trying to learn Scala through a sample project that I have. In it there is a variable record defined as:

```
val records: Iterator[Product2[K, V]]
```

It is passed around in different methods. I explore its contents using :

```
records.foreach(println)
```

However, when I try to print the contents using this iterator **again**, even in successive lines of code, I get no results. It seems as if the iterator is consumed. How do prevent it from happening and be able to explore the contents of the iterator without rendering it useless for the rest of the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An [`Iterator`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) extends `TraversableOnce` and hence can only be iterated over once, as it represents a mutating pointer into an [`Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable). If you want something that can be traversable repeatedly and without affecting multiple, parallel accesses, you need to use the `Iterable` instead, which extends `Traversable` and on `foreach` creates a new `Iterator` for that specific context

Comment: Yup, and for example, calling `.toStream` on the iterator (`Stream` is a subtype of `Iterable`) is one way to get a structure that can be traversed repeatedly (yet, because it is lazy, does not immediately traverse past the first item).

Comment: @Arne Claassen, is there a way to convert an **Iterator** to an **Iterable**. I am asking because I am working on a project which uses Iterator throughout its classes and traits and it is impossible for me to change them all to **Iterable**.

Comment: @HaseebJaved `Iterator` has `.toIterable` or even `toList`, `toVector`, etc. The only caveat here is that `Iterator` wasn't used in the first place to stream data from some _IO_ source because materializing it to an in-memory `Traversable` was prohibitive

Comment: @ArneClaassen I understand that but what if I want to verify the contents of the iterator to check if the code I have written to interact with the iterator does indeed work the right way, or what if I wanted to debug the code?

Comment: The problem you face for testing/debugging is that you cannot convert that `Iterator` to  a `Traversable` without consuming it. The only option (likely not a very feasible one) is to collect the values as you iterate over the `Iterator` into some `Traversable` collection for later verification.

Comment: @ArneClaassen Just to confirm, using the `.toStream` or `.toIterable` will also consume the concerned `Iterator`, right?

Comment: @HaseebJaved Correct. `toIterable` will consume it immediately and `toStream` will consume it lazily, i.e. only as the stream is consumed

Comment: Just to note that `toIterable` is deprecated as of 2.13.0. It's now: `.to(Iterable)`